# Adding a Line to a pdf using iTextsharp Error cant see the Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I have a PDF File and I am trying to put a line in it using iTextSharp like this.

```
string Oldfile = @"C:\ThisTest.pdf";
    string NewFile = @"C:\NewOne.pdf";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Oldfile);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    Document document = new Document(Size);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(NewFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter weiter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = weiter.DirectContent;
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
    cb.BeginText();
    string text = "Haseeb Ahmad";
    cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
    cb.EndText();
    PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    document.Close();
    fs.Close();
    weiter.Close();
    reader.Close();
```

I am trying to add a line to the end of this Document but after it does that code it creates the file and when I open it i cant see that text. When i do a search for that word it says its's there. Like this 
[image: the search shows that line is here but i cant see it]

That mean the code worked all the problem is the font can any one tell me how to make it come to the end of the page and show up instead of being hidden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code first draws the text

```
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
cb.BeginText();
string text = "Haseeb Ahmad";
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
cb.EndText();
```

and thereafter copies the original page into this

```
PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

Thus, your original page contents (which may include a white background fill) cover your new text.

Please change the order, copy the page first and then write the text.

---

If your task is indeed *putting some text onto existing pages of an existing PDF*, you should use other iText classes entirely: `PdfStamper` is made for just this kind of task while the `PdfWriter` is more made for creating new PDFs from scratch.

Your approach is quite lossy (it drops document level information and interactive parts like form fields) while `PdfStamper` keeps as much of the original PDF as possible.

Comment: Ok let me try this quickly. Ok that worked so how to i use the pdfstamper instead of the writer whats the code tho  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Haseeb That's a different question. Don't use comments to ask new questions as such a question usually can't be answered in a comment field in a convenient way. Also: your question isn't clear. What is your problem? What have you tried? Did you do any effort looking for one of the many `PdfStamper` examples that are available online?

Comment: On it right now. Sorry for the miss comment i was suppose to create a a question I will post that question soon Stack over flow wont let me post before 90 minutes so gotta wait.